# Return value from DB is multiple

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, arraylist

I am developing EComerceDocumentManageSystem and need some help. I try to explain. I am have a list of object after searching like this

```
List<DeputeAppeal>deputeAppealList = deputeAppealService.individualSearch(deputeAppealForRequestDto);
model.addAttribute("deputeAppealList", deputeAppealList);
```

service is

```
public List<DeputeAppeal> individualSearch(DeputeAppealForRequestDto deputeAppealForRequestDto) {

        RequestForDeputeAppealSearch requestForDeputeAppealSearch = new RequestForDeputeAppealSearch();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.sql.Date incomeDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch;
        java.sql.Date outDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch;

        if(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getOutDate() == "") {
            deputeAppealForRequestDto.setOutDate(null);
        } else {
            try {
                Date outDateForSearch = format.parse(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getOutDate());
                outDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch = new java.sql.Date(outDateForSearch.getTime());
                requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setOutDate(outDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        if(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getIncomingDate() == "") {
            deputeAppealForRequestDto.setIncomingDate(null);
        } else {
            try {
                Date incomingDateForSearch = format.parse(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getIncomingDate());
                incomeDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch = new java.sql.Date(incomingDateForSearch.getTime());
                requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setIncomingDate(incomeDateForDeputeAppealSQLSearch);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setOutNumber(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getOutNumber());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setIncomeNumber(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getIncomeNumber());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setNameAndAddressOfApplicant(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getNameAndAddressOfApplicant());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setNameOfDepute(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getNameOfDepute());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setSendingOrganization(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getSendingOrganization());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setShortContentOfAppeal(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getShortContentOfAppeal());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setMainWorker(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getMainWorker());
        requestForDeputeAppealSearch.setTypeOfDeputeAppeal(deputeAppealForRequestDto.getTypeOfDeputeAppeal());
        return deputeAppealDao.individualSearch(requestForDeputeAppealSearch);
    }
```

dao is

```
public List<DeputeAppeal> individualSearch(RequestForDeputeAppealSearch deputeAppealForRequest) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionDao.getSession().createCriteria(DeputeAppeal.class);
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getOutNumber().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("outNumber", deputeAppealForRequest.getOutNumber()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getIncomeNumber().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("incomeNumber", deputeAppealForRequest.getIncomeNumber()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getNameAndAddressOfApplicant().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("nameAndAddressOfApplicant", deputeAppealForRequest.getNameAndAddressOfApplicant()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getNameOfDepute().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("nameOfDepute", deputeAppealForRequest.getNameOfDepute()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getSendingOrganization().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sendingOrganization", deputeAppealForRequest.getSendingOrganization()));
        }
        if(deputeAppealForRequest.getOutDate() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("outDate", deputeAppealForRequest.getOutDate()));
        }
        if(deputeAppealForRequest.getIncomingDate() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("incomingDate", deputeAppealForRequest.getIncomingDate()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getShortContentOfAppeal().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("shortContentOfAppeal", deputeAppealForRequest.getShortContentOfAppeal()));
        }
        if(deputeAppealForRequest.getTypeOfDeputeAppeal() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("typeOfDeputeAppeal", deputeAppealForRequest.getTypeOfDeputeAppeal()));
        }
        if(!deputeAppealForRequest.getMainWorker().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("mainWorker", deputeAppealForRequest.getMainWorker()));
        }
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

when i am use this methods all works fine for searching but it system have a property adds file to each document. Look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadingPageFileForDeputeAppeal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                             @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) int id,
                             Model model){
        LOGGER.debug("Receive request to add file");
        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            try {
                byte [] bytes = file.getBytes();
                DeputeAppeal deputeAppeal = deputeAppealService.getById(id);
                //Creating the directory to store file
                String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
                File directory = new File(path + File.separator + "DeputeAppealsFiles" + File.separator + deputeAppeal.getIncomeNumber());
                if(!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                DeputeAppealFiles deputeAppealFiles = new DeputeAppealFiles();
                deputeAppealFiles.setDeputeAppeal(deputeAppeal);
                deputeAppealFiles.setFilePath(serverFile.getAbsolutePath());
                deputeAppealFiles.setFileType(file.getContentType());
                deputeAppeal.getDeputeAppealFiles().add(deputeAppealFiles);
                deputeAppealService.editFilePath(deputeAppealFiles);
                model.addAttribute("deputeAppealId", deputeAppeal);
                model.addAttribute("fileDirection", deputeAppealFiles.getFilePath());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + file.getName() + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + file.getName()
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }

        return "deputeAppealView/addedFile";
    }
```

so after adding one file document all in searching looks good too but when I am adding two files to each document, searching result page shows me two the same objects, if am adding three files, it show three objects. I am confuse, because I need only one object

Entities below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPUTES_APPEAL")
public class DeputeAppeal extends Appeal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DeputeAppeal_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TypeOfDeputeAppeal")
    private String typeOfDeputeAppeal;

    @Column(name = "sendingOrganization")
    private String sendingOrganization;

    @Column(name = "outNumber")
    private String outNumber;

    @Column(name = "outDate")
    private Date outDate;

    @Column(name = "countOfPages")
    private String countOfPages;

    @Column(name = "nameOfDepute")
    private String nameOfDepute;

    @Column(name = "incomeNumber")
    private String incomeNumber;

    @Column(name = "incomingDate")
    private Date incomingDate;

    @Column(name = "themeOfAppeal")
    private String themeOfAppeal;

    @Column(name = "shortContentOfAppeal")
    private String shortContentOfAppeal;

    @Column(name = "unitWhoDoResolution")
    private String unitWhoDoResolution;

    @Column(name = "contentOfResolution")
    private String contentOfResolution;

    @Column(name = "checkForPlagiarism")
    private String checkForPlagiarism;

    @Column(name = "nameAndAddressOfApplicant")
    private String nameAndAddressOfApplicant;

    @Column(name = "dateForCheck")
    private Date dateForCheck;

    @Column(name = "mainWorker")
    private String mainWorker;

    @Column(name = "secondaryWorkers")
    private String secondaryWorkers;

    @Column(name = "statusOfWorking")
    private String statusOfWorking;

    @Column(name = "result")
    private String result;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deputeAppeal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<DeputeAppealFiles> deputeAppealFiles = new ArrayList<DeputeAppealFiles>();
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DeputeAppealFiles")
public class DeputeAppealFiles implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5227566248002296042L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DeputeAppealFiles_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int deputeAppealFilesId;

    @Column(name = "FilePath")
    private String filePath;

    @Column(name = "FileType")
    private String fileType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DeputeAppeal_ID")
    private DeputeAppeal deputeAppeal;
```

Can someone help? I am lost in java )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem actually comes from DB level. Since you have `FetchType.EAGER` in your `@OneToMany`, Hibenate generates query with join, which produces [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `DEPUTES_APPEAL` and `DeputeAppealFiles`. That is why you get same entity multiple time.

To fix this you can either:

1. Remove `FetchType.EAGER`
2. Use result transformer `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`

P.S. You question title does not correlate with your actual question.

Comment: I am try to remove FetchType.EAGER but get next problem when add file to document  'failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.oleg.project.domain.Appeal.DeputeAppeal.deputeAppealFiles, could not initialize proxy - no Session.jsp

Comment: This problem is not related to your original one and can be solved by looking at first five google search results for given error message. Which all lead to SO btw.

Comment: I use you first recommend  and all works fine, my problem with "no session" i resolved with adding @Transactional annotation